# Can I stack multiple effects in one filter on spark-ar?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Is it possible for me to create a single filter with multiple effects or multiple fixed target trackers using a Native UI picker on Spark AR?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the native-ui, yes, it's marked on the Spark-AR Documentation